# preference for a list of words

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm building an Android app whose settings include a blacklist, so the user can input a list of words. I took a look at the `TextPreference` but it doesn't really fit the scope since it's a dialog with little space.

[image]

Is there any preference (built-in or library) I can use for inserting a list of words? A bigger text area with no dialog should be enough. I didn't think that such a simple preference is not available.

Comment: ListPreference, maybe? Simply add a string array of words and you should be good to go.

Comment: I don't get how this would work since the user should be able to input any word he wants

Comment: You specifically asked for "a list of words". What's best at handling a list if not a ListView (of which ListPreference is a derivate)?

Comment: I have only so much space in the title, I'm explaining the problem better in the question

Comment: You probably have to implement your custom preference type. Something I would call a SearchViewPreference.

Answer (score 2):

Storing a blacklist of words is probably a little out of scope for `SharedPreferences`, since they are designed to maintain simple key:value pairs.

You should create a new Fragment that allows users to manage the blacklist and then implement your own data persistence. If you use Sqlite and create a clustered index on the column `word`, you will have O(log(n)) search. Opposed to O(n) search that scanning the csv values of shared preferences would yield.

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in preferences that provide behavior like that. Also no libraries that i know of.

I recommend creating a custom Preference for this. Internally the preference-v7 layouts setttings screen contains a RecyclerView. So you need to override some sort of ViewHolder logic (PreferenceViewHolder)

This could be usefull: http://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/